# [bash]how to update folder's content

Tags: bash, stat

this is my situation:

I've two folders (A1 and B1) and I want that every files and subfolders contained in A1 are copied into B1 with a timestamp. I want also, that if a file is modified, it must be copied into B1 with a new timestamp.

so:

```
A1 contains: pluto.txt pippo(empty folder)

B1 contains: pluto_timestamp.txt pippo(empty folder)
```

after 2 days:

```
A1 contains: pluto.txt pippo(empty folder)

B1 contains: pluto_timestamp.txt pluto_timestamp2days.txt pippo(empty folder)
```

my idea is:

launch *stat* command recursively of A1 and save output into a txt file.

like a poller, when my script is scheduled, I want to check every file's *modify field*, to see if some files have been modified. maybe I can do that with another launch of *stat* command

```
PSEUDOCODE

while (A1 =! empty) {

open stat_result.txt

if file_A1 already exists in_B1

       if modify_date_A1 =! modify_date_B1

                cp file_A1_TIMESTAMP into B1

       else do nothing

else 

   cp file_A1_FILESTAMP into B1  #because it doesn't exist yet

}
```

hope that it can be more clear. thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
rsync --archive --dry-run A1/ B1/
```

https://stackoverflow.com/tags/rsync/info

Comment: I don't Ghini it's what i need since maybe i want to manipulate namefile in B1, for example

Comment: Then please edit your question to reflect that fact. "must have the same version of the files (or subfolders) of A1 into B1" has no mention of it. But you could still manipulate files in B1 after the rsync.

Answer (score 0):

```
# first create the directories in B1, if they do not already exist
# then copy the timestamped files to B1, if they are not there yet
(cd A1; find -type d)|(cd B1; xargs mkdir -p)
(cd A1; find -type f)|
while read file
do  cp -n A1/$file B1/$(<<<$file sed "s,.*/[^.]*,&_`date -rA1/$file +%F_%T`,")
done
```